# what is the procedure to program bootloader HEX file to the Xmega256A3BU avr board?

Tags: embedded, atmel, atmelstudio

I devolouped ATXMEGA256A3bu devoloupment board. Now  i need to run this by progamming bootloader HEX file. am not getting how to make it work. i need to put loader with JTAG programmer or PDI or SPI. Can any one please help me out how to resolve this issue. any usefull information is much appreciated.

Comment: Does not your JTAG dongle come with a driver and stuff?

Comment: yes you need to use one of those.  I dont think spi works on an xmega, its serial interface is more painful than other avrs but still doable.  It is all documented in the avr documentation on how to do it yourself if you have some other thing you can bit bang with, I think I used a $5 msp430 launchpad (was a sale price now at $10) plus software I wrote.  prolly easier to just buy an inexpensive isp cable/box/board that supports xmega.